# Unable to set public file url expiry to more than 1 year for Azure cloud storage accounts in c# code

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-storage-account, azure-storage-files

Trying to create a shared access signature (SAS) Uri for a file which in azure storage accounts. But getting an error when we set expiry to 10000 years
Error: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime

Is this not possible? Please help.

```
BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
{             
   sasBuilder.ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(10000);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding just 1000 years and seeing if this is possible, I'm pretty sure 23:59:59.9999999 UTC, December 31, 9999 is the maximum date allowed by date time

Comment: Thanks @Roe.  I have tried 1000 years it works.
DateTime.MaxValue  works fine and adds 9999 years

Comment: Glad you were able to get it sorted @Shashimk, do not forget to mark the answer as accepted that way people can see that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure 23:59:59.9999999 UTC, December 31, 9999 is the maximum date allowed by a `DateTime`. Consider using [`DateTime.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.maxvalue?view=net-7.0) or adding less total years. My preference would be the built in `MaxDate` this way you never run into the same issue again

To my knowledge it is not a valid `BlobSasBuilder` object if you leave out the expiration date. So sadly you cannot simply leave the field empty